# Postgres using a single process despite having 64 cores and setting max_worker_processes to 32

Tags: postgresql, parallelism

I'm running Postgres 14 on Ubuntu with 64 cores/ 128 threads and 128GB of memory. I need to run large aggregation jobs daily. The one table that I need to aggregate on is current 1.4 billion rows.

Basically doing anything with this DB will **not use more than one process per query**. Once `SELECT count(*)` ran 8 parallel workers, but even this isn't reliable.

Here are my settings:

```
cpu_index_tuple_cost 0 
cpu_operator_cost 0
cpu_tuple_cost 0
max_logical_replication_workers        | 4                 
 max_parallel_maintenance_workers       | 32               
 max_parallel_workers                   | 32               
 max_parallel_workers_per_gather        | 32               
 max_pred_locks_per_page                | 2                
 max_pred_locks_per_relation            | -2               
 max_pred_locks_per_transaction         | 64               
 max_prepared_transactions              | 50
maintenance_io_concurrency             | 10   
 maintenance_work_mem                   | 64000MB                                 
 max_connections                        | 1000                                    
 max_files_per_process                  | 1000
```

I have tried setting every other setting to be very permissive so I can use more of this powerful machine. I would really like to stick with pure Postgres to run these aggregations instead of using code, which I thought would be easy. But I'm a few hours into getting this to work now.

The user is postgres and because it did, one time, spin up parallel workers for the count, I believe it is not an OS permissions issue. There are 12 postgres user processes currently running.

My read table has no foreign keys, and 3 indexes.

Here is an example query (that has been obfuscated but does run) that runs one process only (all of the jobs do except sometimes `SELECT count(*)` runs 8):

```
WITH std_devs AS (
    SELECT
        a,
        b,
        c,
        STDDEV(d) AS std_dev
    FROM
        table_name
    GROUP BY
        a, b, c
)
INSERT INTO event_records_avg
    (a, b, c, std_dev)
SELECT
    std_devs.a,
    std_devs.b,
    std_devs.c,
    std_devs.std_dev
FROM
    std_devs
ON CONFLICT (a, b, c)
DO UPDATE SET
    std_dev = excluded.std_dev;
```

Appreciate any help getting this to run more parallel.

I tried `EXPLAIN ANALYZE ... LIMIT 1000` and adding a timeout but it just times out prior to completion so I couldn't see the query plan.

Answer (score 3):

Data modifying statements are never parallelized, and there is nothing you can do about that. See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/when-can-parallel-query-be-used.html) for the current restrictions on parallel query.

---

The rest of my answer are tips how you can use parallel query to your advantage with statements where it is supported.

If you really have only a single query running, you should set `max_parallel_workers` and `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` to 64, so that a single query can use all resources.

The number of parallel processes actually used depends on `min_parallel_table_scan_size` and `min_parallel_index_scan_size` and a heuristics:

- if the limit is exceeded, PostgreSQL plans a single parallel worker
- if the table or index exceeds three times the limit, a second worker is planned
- if the table exceeds nine times the limit, a third worker is planned, and so on

So the number of parallel workers grows logarithmically. The idea is that even scanning a large table won't use up all resources. However, you can override these heuristics by setting the storage parameter `parallel_workers` on the table. If you want a scan of a table to use more parallel workers, adjust `parallel_workers` on that table.

Comment: Complaining is easy, coming up with a concept how data modifying statements can be parallelized not so much. Anyway, you got your question answered.